# Use grep command but only for the last lines of a file?

Tags: bash, shell, grep, tail

How can I perform a grep on only the 'tail' of a file?

I am trying to run this command:

```sh
grep 'TEST COMPLETE' -L *.log
```

TEST COMPLETE appears in the last couple lines, this command lists all the files in the folder that have not yet finished the test (Because of `-L`). The logs are very big though so `grep` is very slow.

On the other hand I can pipe grep on the tail. The grep is pretty much instant:

```sh
tail *.log | grep 'TEST COMPLETE'
```

However I cannot use the `-l` or `-L` arguments as I am now grepping the pipe input and not a file. So running it with the list files argument:

```sh
tail *.log | grep 'TEST COMPLETE' -L
```

Will just output: `(standard input)`

Is there any way I can just get `grep` to search on the last 10 lines or something like that?

Comment: Are you REALLY running tail on multiple log files at once as we're all assuming or are you actually just running it on 1 log file but used `*.log` to avoid making up a name for the file?

Comment: Yes. Running it on too many files to be able to sift through this manually. If it was just one file I wouldn't need this command as I can just do `tail file.log` and see if it is complete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just do it in a `for` loop:

```
for log in *.log; do
   if ! tail "$log" | grep -q 'TEST COMPLETE'; then
      echo "$log"
   fi
done
```

Comment: That works thank you! Is there any purpose for quoting the variables?

Comment: [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Comment: The accepted answer in that referenced question has the thought process backwards - quotes aren't something you **add** when you need to, they're something you **remove** when you need to. Always wrap strings and scripts in single quotes unless you **need** to use double quotes (e.g. to let a variable expand) or **need** to use no quotes (e.g. to do globbing and file name expansion). [@tripleee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27701642/1745001) to that question is better but see also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
for f in *.log; do  tail "$f" | grep -q 'TEST COMPLETE' || echo "$f"; done
```

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted, but I would guess that it's because you have the logic inverted. OP wants to print out the names of files that *don't* contain `TEST COMPLETE`. But yeah, your answer is basically the same as mine if you change the `&&` to `||`, and quote the `$f`. This should have been a comment, not a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `tail *.log` puts `==> filename <==` between each file and that string doesn't occur in any of the files:

```
tail *.log |
awk 'gsub(/^==> | <==$/,""){if (f) print f; f=""} /TEST COMPLETE/{f=FILENAME} END{if (f) print f}'
```

Answer (score -2):

`tail -n10 FILENAME` Will give you the last 10 lines of the file. You can then pipe this into grep as done in your question.

Comment: OP knows this. The problem is how to make it work with `grep -L` (note the `-L`).